# Scale ImageView with a slider

Tags: javascript, image, titanium

I have a (nearly) quadratic ImageView containing an image and a slider which should allow the user to zoom the image within the ImageView borders. The image should always stick to the borders of the ImageView so I want a zoom function without any dimensions changing. At the moment my image is already initialized too big and gets bigger and bigger if I trigger the slider.

My xml:

```
<View id=imageContainer>
    <ImageView id="picture" top="0" left="30" height="120" width="120"></ImageView>
    <View id="imagePreferences">
        <Label id="scaleLabel">Foto skalieren</Label>
        <Slider id="scaleSlider" onChange="scalePicture"></Slider>
    </View>
</View>
```

My tss

```
"#imageContainer": {
    top: "80",
    left: "0",
    height: "120",
    width: "90%"
}
"#picture": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "120",
    width: "40%"
}
"#imagePreferences": {
    top: "0",
    right: "0",
    height: "120",
    width: "40%"
}
"#scaleLabel": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "10",
    font: {
        fontSize: 8
    }
}
"#scaleSlider": {
    top: "10",
    left: "0",
    min: "0",
    max: "100",
    value: "0",
    height: "10",
    thumbImage: "/media/slider_btn.png"
}
```

And my js:

```
var image;
var imageSet = false;
var imageMatrix; 

var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "savedChallengeImage.jpeg");
if(file) {
    $.picture.setImage(file);
    image = file;
    imageSet = true;
    imageMatrix = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix(); 
}
function scalePicture(e) {
    if (imageSet) {
        var scale = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
        imageMatrix = imageMatrix.scale(e.Value);
        scale.transform = imageMatrix;
        scale.duration = 0;
        $.picture.animate(scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set the `min : '-10'` `max : '10'` and `value : '0'` for `#scaleSlider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. After reading [this entry](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121257/imageview-zooming) I decided to try the same. The solution is to wrap the imageView in a scrollView.

My new xml:

```
<ScrollView id="imageScrollView">
    <ImageView id="picture"></ImageView>
</ScrollView>
```

My new tss:

```
"#imageScrollView": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "120",
    width: "47%",
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: "false",
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: "false",
    maxZoomScale: "10",
    minZoomScale: "1",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
}
"#picture": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
}
"#scaleSlider": {
    top: "10",
    left: "0",
    min: "1",
    max: "10",
    value: "1",
    height: "10",
    thumbImage: "/media/slider_btn.png"
}
```

And last but not least my js. Please note that I also need to rotate my imageView in another function which caused several problem when using the same 2D Matrix so I provide the rotation code as well.

```
var image;
var imageSet = false;
var imageMatrix;
var rotation = 0;
var scaleValue = 1;

var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "Image.jpeg");
if(file) {
    $.picture.setImage(file);
    image = file;
    imageSet = true;
    imageMatrix = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix(); 
}

var profilePictureState = function() {
    Ti.API.info('Switch value: ' + $.profilePictureSwitch.value);
};

function rotate() {
    if (imageSet) {
        rotation += 1;
        rotation = rotation%4;

        var spin = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
        spin.duration = 0;

        imageMatrix = imageMatrix.rotate(90); 
        spin.transform = imageMatrix;
        $.picture.animate(spin);
    } 
}

function scalePicture(e) {
    if (imageSet) {
        var scale = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
        imageMatrix = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix(); 
        imageMatrix = imageMatrix.rotate(90*rotation);
        scale.duration = 0;
        scaleValue = e.value.toFixed(2);
        imageMatrix = imageMatrix.scale(parseFloat(scaleValue), parseFloat(scaleValue));
        scale.transform = imageMatrix;
        $.picture.animate(scale);       
    }
}
```

I still need to adjust the zooming function a little bit but at least in the iOs simulator it works pretty smoothly.